# It's possible use Cramer's Rule in a non-square Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I search in internet and I only found square matrix examples.

It's possible use Cramer rule to resolve this matrix .

From what I see, I  would have to use a different method to solve it, because I  can not add the two columns next to the matrix, as the cramer rule says.

Independent terms 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    11 \\
    9  \\
    53 \\
    15\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Matrix
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & -1 & 2 \\
    -2 & 3 & 8 \\
    -7 & 5 & -6 \\
    4 & -1 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: There is no Cramer's rule for non-square matrices. It doesn't mean you cannot use it somehow. For example, if your system is: $$\begin{align}3x-y+2z=11\\-2x+3y+8z=9\\-7x+5y-6z=53\\4x-y=15\end{align}$$ why not use Cramer's rule to solve the first three equations, and then check that the (hopefully unique) solution also fits the fourth equation?

Comment: Ok, but how I know if the fourth equation fits with the matrix ?

Comment: Do I have to state this? When you get $x,y,z$ from the first three equations (by using Cramer's rule), calculate $4x-y$ and see if you get $15$...

Comment: Here is a publication that considers Cramers rule for rectangular matrices: [Akhtyamov et al., "Cramer’s rule for non-singular m × n matrices"](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/38/tmn38p13-19.pdf)